# i need to pause the thread when pause button is clicked

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

i am using two threads when pause button pauseb is clicked only pause text is displaying i need to pause the thread untill button is clicked again

```
handler1=new Handler();
      j=new Runnable(){
        public void run() {

            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams absParams =
                    (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) b2.getLayoutParams();

            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
            int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;


            Random r = new Random();



            absParams.x = r.nextInt(width);
            absParams.y = r.nextInt(height);
            b2.setLayoutParams(absParams);
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(page2.this, R.anim.fade);
            b2.startAnimation(animation);
            handler1.postDelayed(j, 870);
        }};
    handler1.postDelayed(j, 50);





    final Button pauseb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseid);
    pauseb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (pause == false) {
                pauseb.setText("Pause");
                pause = true;

            }

                    else{

                    pauseb.setText("Play");
                    pause = false;
                }
                }

            });


            handler = new Handler();

            t = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Intent d = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Page3.class);
                    d.putExtra("count", count);
                    d.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(d);


                }
            };

            handler.postDelayed(t, 8000);
        }
```

the thread is working for 8 sec when pause button is clicked it should pause the entire activity untill resum

Comment: I don't see threads apart form the UI one.

Comment: handler and handler1

Comment: Handlers are not threads. All the code visible here runs on a single thread : the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

call handler.removeCallbacks(j or t) to remove j or t.

and call handler.postDelayed(j or t, time) to continue your stuff.

by the way, the Handler running Runnable on a Thread where you create the Handler.On your case,It's UI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use Boolean Flag ....

```
    boolean pause = false;
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    pause = true;

    }
});
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

int secs;

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    timeInMillisecond = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()- startTime;
    updatedTime = timeSwapBuff+timeInMillisecond;
    secs = (int)(updatedTime/1000);
    int mins = secs/60;
    secs = secs % 60;
    int milliseconds = (int)(updatedTime % 10000);
    textView.setText( String.format("%02d", secs));
    if(!pause)
        customHandler.postDelayed(this,1000);
    imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

}};
```